# Using `\catcode` inside argument reports "Runaway argument" error

Tags: tex-core

Such a simple text makes me confused

```tex
\def\say#1{The argument is #1, I see it}
\say{\catcode`{=12 \bf Hello}
\bye
```

when TeX fails to compile it and reports

```
Runaway argument?
{\catcode `{=12 \bf Hello}
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \say.
<inserted text>
                \par
<to be read again>
                   \bye
l.3 \bye
```

I guess TeX takes `{` of catcode 1 into token list when reading `` \catcode`{ `` so that an unbalanced argument comes to be. For that, I change the command slightly, just adding an extra `}` at the end:

```tex
\say{\catcode`{=12 \bf Hello}}
```

Now a new error raises:

```
! Too many }'s.
<argument> \catcode `{=12 \bf Hello}

\say #1->The argument is #1
                           , I see it
l.2 \say{\catcode`{=12 \bf Hello}}
```

As you see, it also doesn't work. But if considering the token list, there are two left braces `{` of catcode 1 and two right braces `}` of catcode 2 following, thus the list seems to be in balance (maybe). Obviously TeX doesn't think so.

Finally when I match `` \catcode`{=12 `` with `` \catcode`}=12 ``, it runs successfully:

```tex
\say{\catcode`{=12 \bf Hello\catcode`}=12}
```

This may imply that TeX first collects `` \catcode`{=12 \bf Hello\catcode`}=12 `` as argument to `\say`, then analyzes the token list.

So what happens? What a role does `{` in `` \catcode`{ `` plays here? How does TeX judge whether the argument is balanced or not?

Comment: reading the argument and executing the commands are two different things.  ``\say{\catcode`\{=12 \bf Hello}`` will work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With

```
\def\say#1{The argument is #1, I see it}
```

the code

```
\say{\catcode`{=12 \bf Hello}
\bye
```

is illegal, because `{` hasn't yet received category code 12, so TeX looks for a matching `}` and doesn't find it. Upon hitting `\bye`, which is illegal in a macro argument, TeX stops with the error about a “Forbidden control sequence”.

If you add a closing brace

```
\say{\catcode`{=12 \bf Hello}}
```

then the argument is properly balanced. Now TeX will do macro replacement and the input stream will become

```
The argument is \catcode`{=12 \bf Hello}, I see it
```

where *there is* an unbalanced `}`.

As Ulrike suggests,

```
\say{\catcode`\{=12 \bf Hello}
```

would produce no errors. An alphabetical constant consists of a back quote (category code 12) and either a single character or a single character control sequence.

For instance, in order to change the category code of `%` you *must* say

```
\catcode`\%=12
```

in order to avoid TeX taking `%` as the comment character. Some characters *must* always be escaped in this context:

1. characters with category code 0
2. characters with category code 5
3. characters with category code 9
4. characters with category code 14
5. characters with category code 15

All others *can* be escaped and some *must* depending on where you are. For instance `#` should be escaped if you're writing a definition

```
\def\foo{\catcode`#=12 }
```

wouldn't work, but

```
\def\foo{\catcode`\#=12 }
```

would. Similarly for braces in a ⟨balanced text⟩.

Exercise: guess what would you get from

```
\edef\foo{\catcode`\^^M=12 }
\foo
\showthe\catcode`\^^M
```

Comment: Got it! So when TeX scans ``\say{\catcode`{=12 \bf Hello}``, it splits the line into tokens as `\catcode`, `` ` ``, `{`, `\bf` and `H`, `e`, etc., where `{` is still of catcode 1 but not 12 since TeX doesn't yet do the assignment at that time, hence it searches for a matching `}` but fails, which leads to an error. Thanks for your answer, egreg :-)

Comment: @wuxj Changing category codes is a hard topic to master… Did you try the exercise?